# Web service de JSON a xml c#

Tags: c#

Buenas compañeros estoy intentando crear un ws en .net  tengo un JSON pero debo devolver en XML

Me explico mejor 
Debo consumir  ws que me retorna un JSON  y debo dar como respuesta un xml con los datos obtenidos
Nota: Estoy iniciando en c#
adjunto el método con el que estoy trabajando

```
 [WebMethod]

public string Prueba()
    {

        var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30";

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var datos = wc.DownloadString(url);
        var rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Objetos.Resultados>(datos);


        foreach (var persona in rs.results) {
            var nombre = persona.cell;

            return nombre;
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: y ? agrega el codigo que intentastes.

Comment: Debes agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora sino tu pregunta terminará cerrada.

Comment: Mas allá de mi respuesta es realmente facil realizar una busqueda en google para obtener este mismo resultado. Tambíen deberías completar la pregunta con lo que hiciste y que impedimentos encontraste.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 por favor...

Comment: en que estas haciendo el web service?

Answer (score 0):

Te copio un ejemplo.

```
// Para convertir un nodo xml dentro de un string a un json
XmlDocument documento = new XmlDocument();
documento.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(documento);

// Para convertir un json contenido en un string a un nodo XML
// To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node
XmlDocument documento = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Algo de documentación: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm